# Powershell Commands/Script to Modify NTFS Permissions for specific path names

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I'm using the Microsoft Sharepoint Migration Tool to copy several hundred user folders into the cloud.

The path to each user folder is the same structurally, basically: \\fileserver\user\<some variation of the user's name>

The existing permissions for each user subfolder, which are inherited from \\fileserver\user, are: File Admins Full Control; SYSTEM Full Control; Authenticated Users Modify

After completing the migration, I want to:

1. Disable Inheritance on every user folder (some folders at a time, not all of them at once)
2. Add only 2 ACEs, the Domain Admins group with Full Control, and the user folder's owner with Read/List/Execute
3. Remove all other groups and users who have any permissions

Is this best done with Powershell, and how can I script it?

Comment: SU has rules: [How to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) as does SO: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Other sites are similar. Each will say this is not a free code writing service. Show your work, show your error

Answer (score 0):

There are built-in cmdlets for this and modules on the MS powerShelGallery.com as well.

This is a very common thing. Well documented all over the web and in Youtube videos. There are lots of sample scripts and nothing stops you from using DOS '*acl*.exe' tools or other like tools in a script. So, this is really not PowerShell specific question, since you could do this in a batch file, or the like as well.

['windows batch set file and folder permissions'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27windows%20batch%20set%20file%20and%20folder%20permissions%27&t=h_&ia=web)

['powershell set file and folder permissions'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20set%20file%20and%20folder%20permissions%27&t=h_&ia=web)

['powershell set file and folder permissions sharepoint'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20set%20file%20and%20folder%20permissions%20sharepoint%27&t=h_&ia=web)

***Always start with the PowerShell help files and the examples there.***

```
# Built-in cmdlets
Get-Command -Name '*acl*', '*ntfs*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#

CommandType Name                                               Version      Source                         
----------- ----                                               -------      ------                         
...                               
Cmdlet      get-Acl                                            3.0.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Security  
Cmdlet      Set-Acl                                            3.0.0.0      Microsoft.PowerShell.Security  
...                  
Application cacls.exe                                          10.0.19041.1 C:\WINDOWS\system32\cacls.exe  
Application chkntfs.exe                                        10.0.19041.1 C:\WINDOWS\system32\chkntfs.exe
Application dsacls.exe                                         10.0.19041.1 C:\WINDOWS\system32\dsacls.exe 
Application icacls.exe                                         10.0.19041.1 C:\WINDOWS\system32\icacls.exe 
#>

# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-Acl).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-Acl).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-Acl -Examples
# Results
<#
Get-Acl C:\Windows
Get-Acl -Path "C:\Windows\k*.log" | Format-List -Property PSPath, Sddl
Get-Acl -Path "C:/Windows/k*.log" -Audit | ForEach-Object { $_.Audit.Count }
Get-Acl -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control" | Format-List
Get-Acl -InputObject (Get-StorageSubsystem -Name S087)
#>
Get-help -Name Get-Acl -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Acl -Online


(Get-Command -Name Set-Acl).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Set-Acl).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Set-Acl -Examples
# Results
<#
$DogACL = Get-Acl -Path "C:\Dog.txt"
Set-Acl -Path "C:\Cat.txt" -AclObject $DogACL
Get-Acl -Path "C:\Dog.txt" | Set-Acl -Path "C:\Cat.txt"
$NewAcl = Get-Acl File0.txt
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -Recurse -Include "*.txt" -Force | Set-Acl -AclObject $NewAcl
#>
Get-help -Name Set-Acl -Full
Get-help -Name Set-Acl -Online



Find-Module -Name '*acl*', '*ntfs*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#

Version     Name                    Repository Description                                                                                                                                       
-------     ----                    ---------- -----------                                                                                                                                       
1.0.1       ACL-Permissions         PSGallery  A couple of ACL utilities, for repairing corrupt permissions and applying permissions for IIS AppPool identities                                  
1.30.1.28   ACLReportTools          PSGallery  Provides Cmdlets for reporting on Share ACLs.                                                                                                     
1.7         ACLHelpers              PSGallery  Modules to help work with ACLs (Access Control Rights)                                                                                            
1.0.1.0     ACLCleanup              PSGallery  A set of tools to help you clean your fileshares access control lists                                                                             
0.1.2       ACLTools                PSGallery  Module for managing NTFS Acls on files and folders                                                                                                
...                                                                                                                    
4.2.6       NTFSSecurity            PSGallery  Windows PowerShell Module for managing file and folder security on NTFS volumes                                                                   
1.4.1       cNtfsAccessControl      PSGallery  The cNtfsAccessControl module contains DSC resources for NTFS access control management.                                                          
1.0         NTFSPermissionMigration PSGallery  This module is used as a wrapper to the popular icacls utility to save permissions to a file and then restore those permissions to a mirror cop...
#>
```